# iphone - Navigating between UITextFields?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I  have seen a lot of iphone apps which provide an easy to use navigation controll for text fields, which contains next previous and done.

1. What is the technique for this? any
   sample code?
2. they also scroll the screen until
   the selected textField is placed on
   top of the keyboard, how do they do
   that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I don't have direct answers, these are the best I could find off the top of my head:

For 1, take a look at [first responders](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW24), it seems to be what you're looking for.

For 2, you will have to make it manually. See [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html).

Comment: I ended up sub-classing UIViewController to reuse this functionality